# Where Is My Memory Wasted?

Tags: windows-8, memory, memory-card, memory-leaks

I have 8 GB Random Access Memory. And have no idea where the major (6 GB) part of it is disappeared (or usually disappears). Total sum of all the MBs listed in the `Task Manager` (I know not all of the are shown in the image but trust me) is about 2 GB.

[image]

So, again where does it disappear? Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Seem `Task Manager` does not show all of the usage info, correct?

Comment: post a picture of RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: I can post it, but  I have already restarted my apps. Is the pic still appropriate? (I mean now its 27% used)

Comment: Run RAMMap when you have the issue again and take a screenshot.

Comment: You don't need to download another utility.  Just run `resmon`.

Comment: You are only display user processes...RAMMap would be be helpful

Comment: Also if your running an integrated graphics card/controller it is most likely sharing your RAM which is generally a decent chunk

Comment: @JasonBristol, good point but no, I am not running integrated graphics card